# Convert hDC to 4bpp bitmap

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, gdi+

I am working on an application that does some GDI+ drawing to an HBITMAP selected in an HDC. After drawing is complete, I need to:

1. Get a bitmap from the hDC
2. Convert that bitmap to 4bpp bitmap
3. Send the raw bits of the 4bpp bitmap to some other method.

I am really lost, and I am really new to GDI+ and handles. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean *pointing at an HBITMAP*? To draw on the bitmap, you'd have it selected in the HDC.

Comment: Yes, by 'pointing at' I meant that the HBITMAP is selected in the HDC.

Comment: GDI+ won't give you any help here.  A 4bpp image requires a palette, 16 colors that best map the colors of the pixel in the original bitmap.  Pretty painful to write yourself and make it look good.  It is certainly best to change the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

[GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the function you'd use for both converting and retrieving raw bits, that is (2) and (3).

If you don't yet have a handle to BITMAP, you'll have to create a new DC with [CreateCompatibleDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), create a compatible bitmap on it and do a BitBlt from source DC to target DC. Then perform GetDIBits on target DC and bitmap to retrieve the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you draw into the HDC, not the HBITMAP. The HBITMAP gets the data drawn through the HDC. You need to create a new bitmap to get the 4bpp data. However such a color depth is too low (16 colors only). Is it palette based? The conversion (reduction of the color depth) may not be really good, or may not work the way you would like. I would suggest reading the RGB values from the 32-bit bitmap, and then convert them to 4bpp using your own code. Otherwise you will rather need an image library instead, which will perform the conversion as needed.